# Use of a control fact

Tags: drools

**UPDATE**

Introduced a control fact to control rules from firing. Facts are

```
Product (sku="zzz")
TextChoiceOption (sku="control", optionValueValue = "xxx")
DimensionOption (sku="dim", widthValue = 29, heightValue = 71)
TextOption (sku="default_tube_size", value="")
TextOption (sku="motorTubeRule", value="N")
```

Only one rule is firing by rule 12 is firing instead of rule 10 or 11.  Based on Salience level rule 10 or 11 should fire with LIFO firing rule 11 but that is not the case.  What is the problem?

```
rule "rule_10"
    salience 390
    no-loop true
    when
        p: Product(sku != 1)
        TextOption(sku="motorTubeRule", value == "N")
        $opt : TextChoiceOption(sku == "motorControl")
        exists (OptionValue(optionValueValue in ("xxx")) from $opt.value)
        DimensionOption(sku == "dim", widthValue <= "72", heightValue <= "120")
        $edi : TextOption(sku == "default_tube_size")
        $ruleFire : TextOption(sku == "motorTubeRule")
    then
        $edi.setValue("1.5"); update($edi);
        $ruleFire.setValue("Y"); update($ruleFire);
end

rule "rule_11"
    salience 390
    no-loop true
    when
        p: Product(sku != 1)
        TextOption(sku="motorTubeRule", value == "N")
        $opt : TextChoiceOption(sku == "motorControl")
        exists (OptionValue(optionValueValue in ("xxx")) from $opt.value)
        DimensionOption(sku == "dim", widthValue <= "96", heightValue <= "96")
        $edi : TextOption(sku == "default_tube_size")
        $ruleFire : TextOption(sku == "motorTubeRule")
    then
        $edi.setValue("1.5"); update($edi);
        $ruleFire.setValue("Y"); update($ruleFire);
end

rule "rule_12"
    salience 380
    no-loop true
    when
        p: Product(sku != 1)
        TextOption(sku="motorTubeRule", value == "N")
        $opt : TextChoiceOption(sku == "motorControl")
        exists (OptionValue(optionValueValue in ("xxx")) from $opt.value)
        DimensionOption(sku == "dim", widthValue <= "102", heightValue <= "120")
        $edi : TextOption(sku == "default_tube_size")
        $ruleFire : TextOption(sku == "motorTubeRule")
    then
        $edi.setValue("2"); update($edi);
        $ruleFire.setValue("Y"); update($ruleFire);
end
```

Comment: Neither rule 10 nor rule 11 should fire because this criteria is not met: `TextOption(sku == "default_tube_size")`.

Comment: Also your problem is that you're calling both `insert` and `update` which is making a mess of things.

Comment: How does insert and update make a mess?   Update is updating a fact and insert is inserting a new fact.  It should be able to handle that.

Comment: I updated the original post with new control fact that just uses update and not insert.  The control fact is preventing rules from running multiple times however the salience is not being used by the engine.

Comment: `insert` adds a new fact and reevaluates all subsequent rules. Then afterwards you call update and reevaluate _again_ all rules using the _original_ inputs plus the modification passed to `update`. My company banned the use of `update` and our product got much better (more stable, faster, accurate); personally i think it's a code smell that identifies poorly designed rule sets.

Comment: Then how do you update a fact from a rule without an update.  Yes the rules get re-evaluated again but that is what should happens when a fact is updated or a fact is inserted.  And it is not all subsequent rules but all rules are re-evaluated.  If updates and inserts make code smell then what is your suggestion to remove them?

Comment: Update is as if you're calling the rules anew. Insert is just putting a new piece of data in and continuing the _existing_ call with the new piece of information. Updates are dangerous because you can end up with infinite loops very easily especially with large code sets; inserts are generally safer and you can use `no-loop` to a certain extent as well.

Comment: ok.  so if you look at the rules above you will see there can't be infinite loops with how the when clause is setup.  So why is rule 12 firing when rule 10 or 11 should be?